# Does SageMaker Feature Store use Athena queries (data virtualization) to make its queries performant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, amazon-sagemaker, feature-store

SageMaker boasts rapid performance for reading data from batch and online. I am wondering what is happening behind the scenes. Are these Athena queries behind the scenes that the feature stores uses? Is it accessing materialized views, or are these queries running against partitioned data in S3 directly (and thus faster due to partitioning rather than materialized views)?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Athena query history in the region where you are using Sagemaker?

Answer (score -1):

The [video](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/feature-store/) goes into the high-level details of FeatureStore and this E2E [sample](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker-featurestore/sagemaker_featurestore_fraud_detection_python_sdk.html#Build-Training-Dataset) shows how to query against the offline data store.